# Slowdown when using parallel strategies in Haskell

Tags: haskell, parallel-processing

I was working through the exercises of Andre Loh's deterministic parallel programming in haskell exercises. I was trying to convert the N-Queens sequential code into parallel by using strategies, but I noticed that the parallel code runs much slower than the sequential code and also errors out with insufficient stack space.

This is the code for the parallel N-Queens,

```
import Control.Monad
import System.Environment
import GHC.Conc
import Control.Parallel.Strategies
import Data.List
import Data.Function

type PartialSolution = [Int] -- per column, list the row the queen is in
type Solution = PartialSolution

type BoardSize = Int

chunk :: Int -> [a] -> [[a]]
chunk n [] = []
chunk n xs = case splitAt n xs of
         (ys, zs) -> ys : chunk n zs

-- Generate all solutions for a given board size.
queens :: BoardSize -> [Solution]
--queens n = iterate (concatMap (addQueen n)) [[]] !! n
queens n = iterate (\l -> concat (map (addQueen n) l `using` parListChunk (n `div`            numCapabilities) rdeepseq)) [[]] !! n


-- Given the size of the problem and a partial solution for the
-- first few columns, find all possible assignments for the next
-- column and extend the partial solution.
addQueen :: BoardSize -> PartialSolution -> [PartialSolution]
addQueen n s = [ x : s | x <- [1..n], safe x s 1 ]

-- Given a row number, a partial solution and an offset, check
-- that a queen placed at that row threatens no queen in the
-- partial solution.
safe :: Int -> PartialSolution -> Int -> Bool
safe x []    n = True
safe x (c:y) n = x /= c && x /= c + n && x /= c - n && safe x y (n + 1)

main = do
        [n] <- getArgs
        print $ length $ queens (read n)
```

The line `(\l -> concat (map (addQueen n) l using parListChunk (n div            numCapabilities) rdeepseq))` is what I changed from the original code. I have seen Simon Marlow's solution but I wanted to know the reason for the slowdown and error in my code.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are you compiling with `-O2` and running with `-threaded -Nn` (where `n` is your cpu count?)

Comment: Note that `-threaded` is a compile time option, not a run time option.  Also, when are you coming back to Baily's, Don?  The taps miss you.

Comment: Don't forget the -rtsopts and the +RTS.

Comment: Even with `-threaded` and stuff his considerations hold. I don't know anything about parallel strategies, but on my machine the threaded version runs about 3 times slower.

Comment: Why would code run slower just by adding the -threaded option? I have code that is doing the same thing. Is this due to improper parallel design/use or something else?

Comment: Eric, Riccardo: The threaded RTS is slower than the non-threaded RTS.  It's just a fact of GHC life.

Comment: @Don I am using O2 , threaded, -rtsopts and -eventlog flags while compiling. Also I am making sure that I always run with n <= 4. I have a quad core machine.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are sparking way too much work.  The `parListChunk` parameter of `div n numCapabilities` is probably, what, 7 on your system (2 cores and you're running with n ~ 14).  The list is going to grow large very quickly so there is no point in sparking such small units of work (and I don't see why it makes sense tying it to the value of `n`).

If I add a factor of ten (making the sparking unit 70 in this case) then I get a clear performance win over single threading.  Also, I don't have the stack issue you refer to - if it goes away with a change to your `parListChunk` value then I'd report that as a bug.

If I make the chunking every 800 then the times top off at 5.375s vs 7.9s.  Over 800 and the performance starts to get worse again, ymmv.

EDIT:

```
[tommd@mavlo Test]$ ghc --version
The Glorious Glasgow Haskell Compilation System, version 7.0.4
[tommd@mavlo Test]$ ghc -O2 so.hs -rtsopts -threaded -fforce-recomp ; time ./so 13 +RTS -N2
[1 of 1] Compiling Main             ( so.hs, so.o )
Linking so ...
73712
real    0m5.404s

[tommd@mavlo Test]$ ghc -O2 so.hs -rtsopts -fforce-recomp ; time ./so 13
[1 of 1] Compiling Main             ( so.hs, so.o )
Linking so ...
73712
real    0m8.134s
```

Comment: Thanks for pointing out that mistake. I actually wanted to divide the partial solutions equally among the cores. Now I have modified it as ` div (length l) numCapabilities` which should be fine. Even after doing it I find that the parallel version is still slower than the sequential version (compiled without -threaded option) and for -N1 option I get the same stack overflow exception. When I try the same for board size 14, the sequential version works fine but the parallel version gives an out of memory error.

Comment: I know this information might not be sufficient, will it help if I can attach the eventlog file for these cases?

Comment: A version of GHC would help along with the code you're currently using and how you are compiling it for each case (including the `-fforce-recomp` flag, I hope).  I don't suggest you use `length l`, just select a large enough value that the sparking is an insignificant cost but a small enough value that you won't notice the time difference between one or two cores doing the work for that one spark.

Comment: I am currently using ghc 7.4.1. The code I am trying to run is the same as above with just the change I mentioned in my comment. The number of sparks created has come down drastically (max is around 60) when I use length. I also tried using other values but still ended up with the error. I compile the file with the -threaded -O2 -fforce-recomp -rtsopts -eventlog flags and run with -N2, -N3, -N4. flags